# How to disable user control from code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have 2 user controls in an ASPX page. By default the second user control should be disabled. In that user control i am having only one text box. So i find the control in the page load event like this:

```
TextBox txtLocation = (TextBox)PI_CompLocationTree.FindControl("txtLocation");
txtLocation.Enabled = false;
```

But i am getting txtLocation as null. How do I get the control in the ASPX page from the ASCX control?

My Updated Code..In Aspx page..

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/PI_CompLocationTree.ascx" TagName="PI_CompLocationTree"
TagPrefix="uc1" %>

 <div id="Div2">
   <div class="location">
      <div class="usLocation">
           <uc1:PI_CompLocationTree ID="PI_CompLocationTree1" runat="server"/>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In Page Load...

```
 PI_CompLocationTree PI_CompLocationTree = new PI_CompLocationTree();

 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var userControl = (PI_CompLocationTree)this.FindControl("PI_CompLocationTree1");
    userControl.EnabledTextBox = false;
 }
```

In ASCX Page...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" CssClass="fadded_text fadded_text_ctrl" Style="width: 260px;
float: left;" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

In ASCX Code Behind...

```
public partial class PI_CompLocationTree : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool EnabledTextBox
    {
        get { return txtLoc.Enabled; }
        set { txtLoc.Enabled = value; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: First `aspx` is a `page` but  `ascx` is a `Control` don't mix this definitions

Comment: I am not mixing..I want to get the textbox control from ascx and i should disable that from my ASPX Code behind....

Comment: Your question now make sense like this:
You got 2 controls in 1 aspx.
Wanted to change `TextBox` `property` `Enabled` which is in 1-st `Control` from codebehind 2-nd `Control`. If you want change this `property` from `aspx` codebehind not ascx of 2-nd `Control` make simply property like @Candie posted before. Rewrite your question to understable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FindControl Methods as Follow..

```
1.  UserControlClass objOfUserControl = (UserControlClass)Page.FindControl("UserControlID");
    TextBox txtLocation= objOfUserControl.FindControl("txtLocation");
    txtLocation.Enabled = false;
```

2.You Can Also use Public Property as Follow

**In User Control Codebehind**

```
public bool TextBoxUSC
{
  set{txtLocation.Enabled = value;}
}
```

**In Aspx Code Behind**

```
UserControlClass.TextBoxUSC=false;
```

**If You are using Master Page**

```
    ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent");//"MainContent" is ContentPlaceHolder's ID

    UserControlClass userCntrl = (UserControlClass)cph.FindControl("UserControlID");
    userCntrl.TextBoxUSC = false;
```

Comment: public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl...here MyUserControl is a class

Comment: Sorry i had done mistake in my above comment.....what is this ("UserControlID");....i am not having any ID for USerControl

Comment: you must be having code like this in your Page designer <uc3:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server" />,this is generated when you put your user control in page...there you can find your user control id..in this case it is "MyUserControl1"

Comment: In page load....PI_CompLocationTree objOfUserControl = (PI_CompLocationTree)Page.FindControl("PI_CompLocationTree1");...But null value is returned....

Comment: do you have Master page...is User Control placed in ContentPlace Holder...Please check and if so please see my edited code...I have done this myself and it is working..this should solve your problem..

Comment: Setting `ctrl.Enabled = false` in code behind removes all existing CSS classes on the control. I find it shocking that Microsoft hasn't fixed this - `disabled` has been around since *version one* of all browsers (except IE, which got round to it in IE 6) - but you can get round it with `ctrl.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Edited**

Make `Enabled` `false` in aspx you can make like this:

Add property to your UC:

```
 public bool EnabledTextBox
 {
    get{return IdTextBox.Enabled;}
    set{IdTextBox.Enabled=value;}
 }
```

then in aspx:

```
IdOfYourUserControlWithProperty.EnabledTextBox = false;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i am getting the error in "PI_CompLocationTree" as 'System.web.ui.page' doesnot the contain the definition for PI_CompLocationTree....

Comment: what is `PI_CompLocationTree` ? have it `runat="server"` attribute?

Comment: PI_CompLocationTree is my UC Name...In that i am having txtLocation Textbox, which has runat server....

Comment: For this "UserControl" ...its showing error like.."is a namespace, but is used like a type.." ...I had given the code in my page load..

Answer (score 0):

Robin You can delete

```
TextBox txtLocation = (TextBox)PI_CompLocationTree.FindControl("txtLocation");
txtLocation.Enabled = false;
```

In your aspx, add forms with runat="server"

Delete also

```
PI_CompLocationTree PI_CompLocationTree = new PI_CompLocationTree();
```

You don't need because you use FindControl

Your work is good

Comment: yes you are in your aspx, you access to DisableTextBox
who is public property of your usercontrol

Comment: Ok i adapted my answer in order to find user control from another user control by passing on page container

Comment: i am having a textbox in user control. i want to disable that from my ASPX Code behind page..

Comment: You adjust Identifiant of user control in FindControl and add runat="server" to your user control

Comment: Adjust Id : (TypeOfUserControl)this.FindControl("Id"); Add runat="server" in your view

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>..This is the Textbox in UserControl...Still i am getting the same error..

Comment: You must select the id of user control in your aspx , in your aspx you execute FindControl,in order to find user control, so you set id of user control, and when you have found user control, you find textbox just with intellissence, because textbox is public in your user control

Comment: "You must select the id of user control..." Whether i should give ID to my UC..If so where should i give...

Comment: var userControl = (TypeOfUserControl)this.FindControl("Id"); in your Init of your aspx

Comment: UC -  public bool EnabledTextBox  { get { return txtLoc.Enabled; } set { txtLoc.Enabled = value; }} ....Page Init -  var userControl = (PI_CompLocationTree)this.FindControl("txtLoc");....userControl.EnabledTextBox = false;.....Still Error

Comment: var userControl = (PI_CompLocationTree)this.FindControl("txtLoc"), replace txtLoc with id of user control ,

Comment: (PI_CompLocationTree)this.FindControl("Your Id of PI_CompLocationTree")

Comment: Replaced txtLoc with User Control ID...But again null is returned..Cant able to get the User Control also....

Comment: have you added runat ="server" to your usercontrol

Comment: it's case sensitive, update all your code in order to finalize with you this work

Comment: place your user control in forms with runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

```
PI_CompLocationTree1.EnabledTextBox = false; //from .aspx page.  There's no need to use FindControl if you've added it statically to the webpage.
```